Icomfor i+ is for heating or cooling?
Want to connect Emerson Sensi thermostat to Lennox icomfort furnace board. Presently four ports has wire: C, I-, I+ and R. Where do I connect I- and I+ on the new thermostat? C has blue and yellow, R has red, I+ has white and I- has green connections.
